# .strip('{}:'.format(key)) sometimes strips last characters

Tags: python, scrapy

`value = div.xpath('normalize-space(.)').extract()[0].strip('{}:'.format(key)).strip()`

The code above sometimes strips the last character from the word. After removing the code after `extract()` all the data came back fine but in a list.

Example :

- `Unknown` from `Duration: Unknown` turns into `unknow`
- `Movie` from `Type: Movie` turns into `Movi`

Why does this happen?

I tried this in Python shell and it also strips the last characters

```
>>> value = ['Type: Movie']
>>> value[0].strip('{}:'.format('Type')).strip()
'Movi'
```

I expect it to return `Movie` instead of `e` getting stripped.

It seems that this `.strip('{}:'.format('Type'))` is responsible. I removed the last strip() it only return data with spaces.

Edit: It seems that `strip()` takes characters in inputted string and remove them instead of removing exact strings. That is why the data came out broken. I think a string split then slice is good.

Edit 2:
Seems like answers by Austin and Pankaj Singhal is good and bug free for my use case.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Do you understand what the different parts of the code are doing, i.e. `[0]`, `strip` or `format`? What is `key`? `strip(string)` will remove all the characters in `string` from the start and end of the word.

Comment: Can show the data source?

Comment: Edited. Check the post again!

Comment: `strip` does NOT do what you think it does.

Comment: I thought it is for removing characters you don't want?

Comment: But you just said you didn't want to remove e in the end of "Movie", so stop using strip.

Comment: Yea, I didn't want to remove strip I just want to remove Type: in Type: Movie. Just occur to me does strip takes the string and remove the character in it the string using the character of the inputted string instead of removing whole strings? Also explain it to me, don't say useless stuff like "stop using strip" because ifI want to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `split` on `'Type: '` and take the second item:

```
value = ['Type: Movie']
print(value[0].split('Type: ')[1])
# Movie
```

Talking about your code, `strip` is not meant for what you are trying to do. `strip` only removes characters from at the ends.

Comment: This will introduce a bug. I only want "key" value + : to be stripped not anything with :

Comment: I'm not stripping anything here. I used `split` function. Could you check it again?

Comment: What I meant is that if you use this method, it will split anything with a ': ' in it. This include the data that I want to collect. For example, if the value is ```Title: Alien: The Beginning```, it will return The Beginning instead of Alien only. Of course you could just get everything after the first but what I want to know is why strip removes the last character on some fields but does not for others when they are in the same format.

Comment: I think I will use your method except that I will get everything after index 0. What do you think? Also a typo, I didn't really want just ```Alien``` but rather ```Alien: The Beginning```

Comment: @KuoChongYii  I am updating my answer to include that too.

Comment: Or maybe I could do a ```split('Type:')[1]``` instead

Comment: Yes, that works. I have updated my answer. :)

Comment: Nice, accepted.

Answer (score 0):

OR:

```
>>> value = ['Type: Movie']
>>> value[0][value[0].find(':')+2:]
'Movie'
>>>
```

And of course, this is another option similar to the first one, just using `lstrip`:

```
>>> value[0][value[0].find(':')+1:].lstrip()
'Movie'
>>>
```

OR:

```
>>> value[0].lstrip(value[0][:value[0].find(':')+2])
'Movie'
```

Note: here `find` can be replaced with `index`

Comment: imo that's crazy long. Not very readable, but I rarely use find and lstrip

Comment: @KuoChongYii `find` can actually be changed to `index`

Comment: That make sense and is more readable because we are not really finding the word but rather what the index is instead of the position of the word.

Comment: @KuoChongYii Edited mine (with a more unreadable one), Also you have enough reputation to upvote so you can do it if you want

Answer (score 0):

[`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) does not strip that exact string, but each character *in* that string, i.e. `strip("Type:")` will remove each `T`, `y`, `p`, etc. from the beginning and end of the string.

Instead, you could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) with the `^` anchor to only match substrings at the beginning of the string.

```
>>> value = ['Type: Movie with Type: in its name']
>>> key = "Type"
>>> re.sub(r"^{}: ".format(key), "", value[0])
'Movie with Type: in its name'
```

Comment: But then it will remove the Type: in the middle. I think a simple string split then slice is good enough for this. Avoids the bugs when you replacing or subsituting characters.

Comment: @KuoChongYii No, it does not. That's exactly what the `^` is there for. (Just realized that I changed the input without updating the output, maybe that was confusing.)

Comment: Oh so it just subsitute the beginning of the string and thats it?

Comment: @KuoChongYii Exactly, `^x` means that `x` has to appear at the very beginning of the string.

Comment: I should learn it but I always get bored on it and there isn't much project I can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip) (which returns a copy of the string with only leading characters removed), instead of [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) (which returns a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters removed):

```
>>> 'Type: Movie'.lstrip("Type:").strip()
'Movie'
>>> 'Type: Something with Type'.lstrip("Type:").strip()
'Something with Type'
>>> 'Type: Something with Type:'.lstrip("Type:").strip()
'Something with Type:'
>>>
```

Comment: Won't work for `"Type: Something with Type:"`

Comment: @tobias_k It's working

Comment: That also reminds me to make sure this does not happen. Thanks @tobias_k

Comment: @PankajSinghal I think what he meant is that it will remove the final Type: too instead of just first one.

Comment: As @tobias_k said, you would end up replacing all `Type:` throughout the sentence. You could use `startswith` here before replacing

Comment: @ThatBird updated

Comment: This works, but rather coincidentally. Without the space after the key, it would still remove any leading `T` from the value.